# Where to see the output of Hello World built by Gradle on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Where can I see the output of Hello World built by Gradle on IntelliJ?

It should print out 'Hello World'.

[image]

Comment: You would have to run the program to see its output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is you built the project, i. e. you compiled the source code. Instead of building your project, you may want to click the Play button next to `public class HelloWorld` and then "Run HelloWorld.main()". This will cause IntelliJ to not only compile your source code but also to run the program

Comment: Okay It works now. I did try that button before, it didn't work. But this time it did.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as the solution if it worked for you? Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Watch out for it in Build tab next to terminal

Answer (score -1):

You can control the verbosity of warnings on the console with the following options:

-Dorg.gradle.warning.mode=(all,none,summary)
Specify warning mode via Gradle properties. Different modes described immediately below.

--warning-mode=(all,none,summary)
Specifies how to log warnings. Default is summary.

Set to all to log all warnings.

Set to summary to suppress all warnings and log a summary at the end of the build.

Set to none to suppress all warnings, including the summary at the end of the build.